# Reverse one word in a sentence

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create a function that reverse a word from a sentence.Partial of my code works fine 
but i am unable to accomplish what i want.Below is the function i created. I only want "language" in 
reverse. The output should be like "Python is an interesting egaugnal to learn".How can i accomplish 
this

```
    def reverse(sentence,reverse_word):
        i = sentence.find(reverse_word)
        reverse_sentence = sentence[:i] + reverse_word[::-1] 
            return reverse_sentence
   reverse("Python is an interesting language to learn","language")
```

The above code reverses the code and returns up to reversed word. I am not able to accomplish the 
   words after the reversed word.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to replace the word with its reversed version

```
text = "Python is an interesting language to learn"
word = "language"
text.replace(word, word[::-1])
```

Outputs

> Python is an interesting egaugnal to learn

Works even if the word occurs multiple times.

---

Note however, that in the above solution `languages` will become `egaugnals`.

If you want to reverse only if the **whole word** matches, use:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\b'+word+r'\b', word[::-1], text)
```

In this solution,

> Python is an interesting language to learn like many other languages

will become

> Python is an interesting egaugnal to learn like many other languages

Comment: What if the word is a partial match like `an`? Should the output be `"Python is na interesting lnaguage to learn"`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse(sentence,reverse_word):
        i = sentence.find(reverse_word)
        k=i+len(reverse_word)
        reverse_sentence = sentence[:i] + reverse_word[::-1] + sentence[k::]
        return reverse_sentence

print(reverse("Python is an interesting language to learn","language"))
```

Output:

Python is an interesting egaugnal to learn

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use `re.sub`, in order to match the word only if it's independent (i.e., not part of another word), and to replace all such matches:

```
import re

def reverse(sentence, reverse_word):
    reverse_sentence = re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % reverse_word, reverse_word[::-1], sentence)
    return reverse_sentence

print(reverse("Python is an interesting language to learn, what a language! languagexxx", "language"))
```

Output:

```
Python is an interesting egaugnal to learn, what a egaugnal! languagexxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the remaining part of the sentence that occur after the reversed word. To do that get the length of the word to reverse and use that to get the start index position of the remaining words, See code below:

```
def reverse(sentence, reverse_word):
    i = sentence.find(reverse_word)
    j = len(reverse_word)
    reverse_sentence = sentence[:i] + reverse_word[::-1] + sentence[i+j:]
    return reverse_sentence
reverse("Python is an interesting language to learn","language")
```